# PHP: Button not proceeding to the next page under IF ELSE

Tags: php, button, if-statement

I have a question. I have a little problem using PHP regards the `IF ELSE`. I have a condition there where, when I choose in the dropdown is "All" the save button will be disabled, and it's working. But, when I choose the "Top" the save button is enabled yet it's not proceeding to the next page.

Before I place it in `IF ELSE`, the save button is working but then when I place it to the `IF ELSE` save button, is not proceeding in the next page.

Below is my code:

```
 $dropdown_value = (string)$_POST["id"];

if ($dropdown_value == 'All') 
{
echo "<input type='submit' name='save' value='Save' disabled onClick='this.form.action='save_data.php'; this.form.submit()'>    ";
$all = mysql_query("SELECT fldBldgName FROM tblbuildings");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($all))
{

echo "<div><input type='checkbox' name='play[]' class='chk_boxes1' value='" . $row['fldBldgName']."'>";
echo $row['fldBldgName'];"</div>";


}
}
else if ($dropdown_value == 'Top') 
{
echo "<input type='submit' name='save' value='Save'  onClick='this.form.action='save_data.php'; this.form.submit()'>    ";
echo "<div><input type='checkbox' class='checkall'> Check all</div>";
$top = mysql_query("SELECT fldBldgName FROM tblbuildings ORDER BY fldBldgName ASC LIMIT 30");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($top))
{
echo "<tr><td>";
echo "<div><input type='checkbox' name='play[]' class='chk_boxes1' value='" . $row['fldBldgName']."'>";
echo $row['fldBldgName'];"</div>";

echo "</td></tr><br/>";
}
}
```

Comment: Can you add the code with the `ALL` and `TOP` in it? It's hard for me to tell how to go about this.

Comment: @Fred...sorry..I already include it

Comment: I see you've gotten an answer. Right on, I'm glad to see it worked out for you, cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have a quote issue

```
onClick='this.form.action='save_data.php'; this.form.submit()'
```

I think the single quotes around `save_data.php` is ending your `onClick`. Since you are echoing this inside php double quotes, try something like

```
onClick=\"this.form.action='save_data.php'; this.form.submit()\"
```

so it is now

```
echo "<input type='submit' name='save' value='Save'  onClick=\"this.form.action='save_data.php'; this.form.submit()\">    ";
```